# C++: misunderstanding memory address and copy values of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, copy, memory-address

I thought I had understood the concept of pointers until going through [this example](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) (see "declaring pointers"), second example, which states the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
  int * p1, * p2;

  p1 = &firstvalue;  // p1 = address of firstvalue
  p2 = &secondvalue; // p2 = address of secondvalue
  *p1 = 10;          // value pointed to by p1 = 10
  *p2 = *p1;         // value pointed to by p2 = value pointed to by p1
  p1 = p2;           // p1 = p2 (value of pointer is copied)
  *p1 = 20;          // value pointed to by p1 = 20

  cout << "firstvalue is " << firstvalue << '\n';
  cout << "secondvalue is " << secondvalue << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

having as result:

```
firstvalue is 10
secondvalue is 20
```

My question is: why is `*p1=firstvalue` not 20 ? Because they share the same memory adress. So as far as I know, one memory adress cannot have 2 different values. 
My reasonning is the following:

```
*p1 = 10 //firstvalue=10, *p2=secondvalue=15
*p2 = *p1 //*p1=firstvalue=secondvalue=*p2=10
p1 = p2 //*p1=*p2, now firstvalue and secondvalue share the same memory adress 
*p1 = 20 //*p2=*p1 (because they have the same memory adress) so firstvalue=secondvalue=20
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `p1 = p2;`  makes `p1` point to `secondvalue` - it does *not* somehow magically move `firstvalue` and `secondvalue` around in memory so they share the same address. Then `*p1 = 20;` assigns to `secondvalue`, not `firstvalue`. It might be illuminating to do something like `cout << p1 << ' ' << p2 << ' ' << &firstvalue << ' ' << &secondvalue;` - this way you could actually see various addresses.

Comment: At the end both pointers point to `secondvalue`

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Oh I see... this idea of memory position was perturbating me. It's much more logical seeing it this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code:

```
p1 = &firstvalue; // p1 = address of firstvalue 
p2 = &secondvalue; // p2 = address of secondvalue
*p1 = 10; // value pointed to by p1 = 10 
*p2 = *p1; // value pointed to by p2 = value pointed to by p1 
p1 = p2; // p1 = p2 (value of pointer is copied) 
*p1 = 20; // value pointed to by p1 = 20
```

Can be rewritten as

```
p1 = &firstvalue; // p1 = address of firstvalue 
p2 = &secondvalue; // p2 = address of secondvalue
firstValue = 10; // value pointed to by p1 = 10 
secondValue = firstValue; // value pointed to by p2 = value pointed to by p1 
p1 = &secondvalue; // p1 = p2 (value of pointer is copied) 
secondValue = 20; // value pointed to by p1 = 20
```